# Is it possible to retrieve values from mongoDB during the creation of a schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am completely new to Nodejs and MongoDB so there might be a very simple answer available for this but I am struggling to find it.

What I am wanting to do is have a table of values that I can retrieve while creating a schema so that if any of those values change, all I have to do is update the database and not write any code. For example, say I have a table of fruit:

- Apples
- Bananas
- Oranges

I want to pull the values out of this table when defining my schema instead of having to do something like this:

```
var fruitSchema = new mongooseSchema({
   fruit: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['Apples','Bananas', 'Oranges'],
    },
})
```

In my mind, it would look something like this:

```
var fruitSchema = new mongooseSchema({
   fruit: {
        type: String,
        enum : [{A database call}],
    },
})
```

Or possibly:

```
const myFruit = {database call}

var fruitSchema = new mongooseSchema({
   fruit: {
        type: String,
        enum : myFruit,
    },
})
```

**A)** Is something like this possible?
**B)** Are there any best practices I should be aware of in terms of implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can run a raw mongodb query. Example:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('fruitCollection').find({ ... })
```

Get your expected data from the collection and the build schema/model based on it.